# Why is "Shanghai" pronounced the way it is in English?

Tags: english, pronunciation, chinese

Most English-language news sources and people in America pronounce the name of the city (上海) with a long a sound as in "way" within the "shang (上)" syllable, but it's not pronounced that way in Chinese; the actual pronunciation of 上 is with the "ah" sound as in "father," and most Chinese dialects pronounce it more similarly to Mandarin than how it's pronounced in English. Why?

Comment: I have never heard anyone say it with "ay" in the first syllable.

Comment: Yes, for many of us, "shang" is like "bang".  "Bang" has the glide of "way" because a "y" glide is inserted between a front vowel and "ng", since in going from the vowel to "ng", the tongue has to go through a "y" position.  Since you tell us that the Chinese vowel is not front, I guess the American English pronunciation is do to the spelling "ang".

Comment: @GregLee Neither "bang" nor "shang" include a glide for me. Also, the vowel is an [a] not an [e]. I'm a Canadian English speaker but I'm almost positive this is true for most American English dialects as well since "bang" pronounced [beng] or [beyng] sounds vaguely Kiwi to my ears (I'm not sure if Kiwis actually pronounce "bang" this way. It sounds foreign, is my point).

Comment: "Bang" is [bæ̃j̃ŋ], for those of us with the inserted glide.  (Before phonetic [ŋ] that is not the phoneme /ŋ/, I do not have a glide, either: "Ban kids! = [bæ̃ŋkɪdz], where the velar nasal is by regressive place assimilation to following [k],

Comment: I'm not so sure most Chinese "dialects" pronounce it so much like in Mandarin: Cantonese: soeng6 hoi2, Hakka: Sông-hói, Min Nan: Siōng-hái, Wu: zaan he.

Comment: What I mean is that other Chinese dialects don't pronounce it like the English pronunciation of the name.

Comment: I cannot think of **any** words that contain the sequence [ɑŋ] in English – without checking further, I suspect it’s phonotactically impossible. Only short /a/ (allophonically lengthened and in some dialects diphthongised) appears to be the only possible a-sound before /ŋ/. So that’s probably part of the reason. (Also, the a-sound in 上 _shàng_, usually [ɑ̟̃], is not the same as that in _father_, usually [ɑ̠ː].)

Answer (score 9):

As a general rule, English speakers don't learn the pronunciation of place names from speakers of that language; they use general rules for pronunciation. Hence [br̩lɪn] instead of [bɛrlin], [ɔzlow] instead of [uʃlu], [pɛrɪs] instead of [paʁi], and Qatar (Standard Arabic [ˈqɑtˤar]) is a real problem, so I've heard [ˈkɑɾṛ], [kəˈtɑr] and [kæɾr̩]. Colin Powell would pronounce it as [gʌtr̩], close to the local dialect pronunciation [ˈgitˤar]. We also never pronounce Mandarin "h" as [x], and "zh" and "j" are not distinguished. Additionally, in American English, front vowels are raised a bit more before the voiced velars (g, ŋ) since there's no tense-lax contrast.

Comment: Actually, some people would distinguish zh and j as /ʒ/ and /dʒ/... that just goes to demonstrate your point.

Comment: Also English just took the transliteration of Chinese into Latin script made by Chinese and did not make its own. So while pinyin is also inspired by English, in many majour ways, it is very different, thus words like "Beijing", "Mao Zedong", "Zhou" or "Qing" get very often totally butchered by English speakers.

Comment: Another relevant example would be - any Polish name. Warsaw is (in my own British English) [wɔːsɔː], not [varˈʂava]

Comment: But Warsaw is an exonym, no? @LeoKing

Comment: I've always found the common pronunciation of Paris especially heinous. If Versailles is never pronounced the way it's spelt, then I see no reason to do any differently for Paris. @user6726

Comment: I've never heard Paris pronounced with the DRESS vowel, always TRAP (at which point the presence of the original s is the only difference not following from simple adaptation to English phonology)

Comment: Not sure I've ever hear it with æ or a, but I imagine it's that way in the UK.